# Can `path` in rsyncd.conf be a file?

Tags: linux, rsync

I would like to only allow `/etc/named.conf` to be synced, so if I in `etc/rsyncd.conf` do

```
[named]
  path = /etc/named.conf
```

and then

```
# OPTS='-aHEXv --password-file=/etc/rsync.secrets'

# rsync $OPTS eeer@ns::named /etc
@ERROR: chroot failed
rsync error: error starting client-server protocol (code 5) at main.c(1648) [Receiver=3.1.2]

# rsync $OPTS eee@ns::named/named.conf /etc
@ERROR: chroot failed
rsync error: error starting client-server protocol (code 5) at main.c(1648) [Receiver=3.1.2]
```

The problem is I don't want to allow the client to have access to anything else than `etc/rsyncd.conf`, so setting `path = /etc` would not be a good solution.

**Question**

Does anyone know how to only allow one file to be rsync'ed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can read the following from `man rsyncd.conf`:

> path
>
> This parameter specifies the directory in the daemon’s filesystem
>   to make available in this module.  You must specify this parameter for
>   each module in rsyncd.conf.

So, this is apparently a directory not a regular file.

As a workaround, I can suggest moving your file to a new directory. If it is a configuration file `/etc/named.conf`, you should be able to point your process to the new location like `/etc/named/named.conf`.